# Ways/Sources to learn writing macros for Microsoft office word

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-word, ms-office

Please someone help me to find sources to learn writing macros for MS Office Word. I am ended up with getting web pages for only "Recording macro" explained in different ways. While seeing those web pages i got to remember the sentence

```
"Sometimes people come up with awful analogies in an effort to describe a concept 
which is too difficult for a regular person to understand.An infinite number of 
monkeys    hitting at an infinite number of typewriters for 
an infinite amount of time will eventually produce all works of Shakespeare."
```

from infinite monkey theorm. Recording macro is very easy one. Most of the writers ended up with writing this article.
Please someone suggest me to learn writing Macros for MS Office Word. I am using Word 2007.

Comment: Are you familiar with programming in general?

Comment: @justnS Ya i know VB, I am trying learn how to present it in MS WORD Way. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already familiar with the syntax, I suggest a site like this (its a cookbook approach): http://www.thezcorp.com/VBACodeSamples.aspx

Also, you can still press F2 to access the object browser and then filter the selection to just the Word library.

Comment: I am not getting object browser with F2

Comment: Sorry. With MS Word activated, press ALT+F11. This will bring you to the VBA IDE. While in the IDE, press F2.